# How to delete a specific string from a line using ansible

Tags: ansible, remove

I have some package added in yum exclude list in /etc/yum.conf and I want to remove a specific package from a exclude list

example:

exclude=java*
exclude=kernel* java*
exclude=java* kernel*
exclude=kernel* abc* java* def*

I tried to  add # but that do not serve the purpose and add comments to all exclude statement.

```yaml
- name: Comment Java exclusion
  replace:
    path: /etc/yum.conf
    regexp: '(.*java*)'
    replace: '#\1'
```

Added more case scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with an empty string.

```yaml
- name: Comment Java exclusion
  replace:
    path: /etc/yum.conf
    regexp: '(java\*\s*)'
    replace: ''
```

Changes to the regex:

- `.*` would have removed the `exclude=` as well, so I removed it
- The `*` needs to be escaped, it's a regex modifier
- added `\s*` to remove trailing whitespace as well

*EDIT*

Even better:

```yml
- name: Comment Java exclusion
  replace:
    path: ~/ansible/test.blah
    regexp: '^(exclude=.*)java\*\s*'
    replace: '\1'
```

This makes sure that only the line starting with `exclude=` is affected and works even when `java*` is not the first item in the list.

Comment: grep exclude /etc/yum.conf
exclude=java*
exclude=kernel* java*
exclude=java* kernel*
exclude=kernel* abc* java* def*
-----------------------------------------

$ grep exclude /etc/yum.conf
exclude=exclude=kernel* exclude=kernel*
exclude=kernel* abc* def*

Comment: It did not work

Comment: It did work perfectly in my tests prior to posting this. If it did not work for you please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I have added below cases also in my question, Can  you please check
exclude=java*
exclude=kernel* java*
exclude=java* kernel*
exclude=kernel* abc* java* def*